# Not able to display the image inspite of getting it from the server. Not any relevant error to debug

Tags: angular

```
<div class="col-md-4 itemList" *ngFor="let item of allitems">
   <mat-card class="example-card">
   <!--this image is not displaying-->
   <img mat-card-image src="{{baseUrl + item.image}}" alt="img">
   <div class="overlay-content">
      <div fxLayout="row">
         <div fxFlex="23">
            <!--i am getting the title but not image-->
            <p>{{item.name}}</p>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <mat-card>
</div>
```

I am trying to display image that is coming from the server. I have one api that content an array like this

```
"Names":[{"name": "rahul","image":"0ea6206b3647fcba4694e48aa8a3a40e.jpg"},{"name": "akshat","image":"akshat.jpg"}]
```

I am loop to iterate over the  data using 
`*ngFor="let name of Names"`
`<p>{{name.name}}</p>`
`<img src="{{name.image}}">`
I am gating the name but not image.
i Also tried `<img src="{{baseUrl + name.img}}">`
baseUrl="url that contain array"

Comment: Your `baseURL` is an array ?

Comment: what do you see in dev console the src??

Comment: If you copy the baseUrl + name.img into address bar of a new tab/window in your browser, do you see an image? If not, there's no image at that url and you might need to change your baseUrl.